# mysql query inner join on same table with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, where-clause

I have a table transactions and I trying to figure out our new customers in a given month. That means that if a customer didn't have a transaction in the time before the month he/she counts as a new customer.

I have figured out a way, but it is seriously inefficient and takes ages. I then came across this [artikel](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) which compares different methods. I have tried to adjust that approach to mine without success.

To visualise my problem:

```
|--------------------------- time period with all transactions -----------------------|
|----- period before month transactions = 0) ---|---- curr month transactions > 0 ----|
```

The table looks like this:

```
transactions
id, email, state, date_paid
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    l.email
FROM
    transactions as l
LEFT JOIN transactions as r ON r.email = l.email
WHERE
    r.email IS NULL
AND l.state = 'paid'
AND r.state = 'paid'
AND l.date_paid <= '2013-12-31 23:59:59'
AND r.date_paid < '2013-12-01 00:00:00'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.email
FROM transactions AS l
LEFT JOIN transactions AS r ON r.email = l.email AND r.state = 'paid' AND r.date_paid < '2013-12-01 00:00:00'
WHERE r.email IS NULL AND l.state = 'paid' AND l.date_paid <= '2013-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I tried both ways and yours is faster by a lot. Can I put in a DISTINCT condition or GROUPED for l.email and if yes where exactly. Don't wanna break the query :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT l.email
FROM transactions l
WHERE NOT l.email IN (SELECT r.email 
                      FROM transactions r
                      WHERE r.state = 'paid' AND r.date_paid < '2013-12-01 00:00:00')
      AND l.state = 'paid' AND l.date_paid <= '2013-12-31 23:59:59'
```